# Creating UICollectionView programmatically (outside of UIViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I would like to create a subclass ofimport UIKit

class AlbumPlayerProgressBar: UICollectionView to later use it in xib. And can't seem to figure out how to properly use init functions

```
import UIKit

class AlbumPlayerProgressBar: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var progressBarType :ProgressBarType = .Player
    var numOfSlides: Int = 0
    var numOfPlayingSlide: Int = 0

    init()
    {
        super.init()

        self.register(UINib(nibName: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self))
    }


    func set(progressBarType :ProgressBarType, numOfSlides: Int, numOfPlayingSlide: Int) {

        self.progressBarType = progressBarType
        self.numOfSlides = numOfSlides
        self.numOfPlayingSlide = numOfPlayingSlide

        self.reloadData()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("AlbumPlayerProgressBar init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numOfSlides
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self), for: indexPath) as! ProgressBarCell

        cell.setType(self.progressBarType)

        if (indexPath.row < numOfPlayingSlide)
        {
            cell.setPlayed()
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == numOfPlayingSlide)
        {
            cell.setPlaying()
        }
        else
        {
            cell.setUnplayed()
        }
        return cell
    }
}


enum ProgressBarType {
    case Player
    case Thumnail
}
```

Comment: subclass of collectionView contains an object of it !!!!

Comment: Removing @Sh_Khan

Comment: @Sh_Khan Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your CollectionView as

```
class AlbumPlayerProgressBar: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    var progressBarType :ProgressBarType = .Player
    var numOfSlides: Int = 0
    var numOfPlayingSlide: Int = 0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        //gets called when you instantiate your collectionView from xib
        self.register(UINib(nibName: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self))
        self.dataSource = self
    } 

    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.register(UINib(nibName: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self))
        self.dataSource = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.register(UINib(nibName: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self))
        self.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numOfSlides
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(ProgressBarCell.self), for: indexPath) as! ProgressBarCell

        cell.setType(self.progressBarType)

        if (indexPath.row < numOfPlayingSlide)
        {
            cell.setPlayed()
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == numOfPlayingSlide)
        {
            cell.setPlaying()
        }
        else
        {
            cell.setUnplayed()
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Depending on how would you initialize/instantiate collectionView decide where would like to register your nib and setting data source as self.

Hope it helps

Comment: @luda : Try instantiating CollectionView in all possible ways like using init and from xib just to make sure nothing is wrong with the code :) Happy coding